# Why does Physica A journal contain economics papers?

Tags: soft-question, statistical-mechanics

Why does Physica A journal contain economics papers? Like this:

> Steve Keen, Russell Standish. Proﬁt maximization, industry structure, and competition: A critique of neoclassical theory. *Physica A* **370** no. 1 (2006), pp. 81–85. [doi:10.1016/j.physa.2006.04.032](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.physa.2006.04.032). Available online at [http:// www. debtdeflation.com/ blogs/wp-content/uploads/papers/ KeenStandish2006_CritiqueNeoclassical TheoryOfFirm_PhysicaA370pp81-85.pdf?](http://www.debtdeflation.com/blogs/wp-content/uploads/papers/KeenStandish2006_CritiqueNeoclassicalTheoryOfFirm_PhysicaA370pp81-85.pdf?)

I thought Physica A is only about statistics mechanics and its application in economics - I don't see how this paper is related to statistical mechanics....

Comment: Unfortunately, such questions are off topic, see the first section of the [faq#questions]. Feel free to ask other questions about physical concepts :)

Comment: @Manishearth OP said *"I don't see how this paper is related to statistical mechanics...."*. That is relevant to physics i guess.

Comment: @dushya: Hmm, I just discussed it in [chat], another mod and a user agree that it's OT. Feel free to chime in, though

Answer (score 2):

The paper does Monte Carlo simulations so I would argue it surely *is* related to statistical mechanics. What about the authors?

[Steve Keen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Keen) is an economist but [Russell Standish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell_K._Standish) is a computer scientist who likes to talk about "ensembles of theories of everything", similarly to Max Tegmark. It's at least a physics-related jargon. For this reason, you may call the paper a research on "physics of the money" instead of "economics" even if it is the same thing.

Still, I would guess the paper was rejected by some economics journal before it was sent to a physics one. But maybe it was rejected because it was too advanced when it comes to the mathematical methods.

Interestingly enough, the [most cited followup paper](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=7277859791018858719&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=en) by Moura and Ribeiro was also published in a physics journal – European Physics Journal B for Condensed Matter Physics. The introduction to [that paper](http://www.if.ufrj.br/~mbr/papers/EPJB.67.101.2009.pdf) is interesting because it talks about some physics methods' being imported to economics. You may want to read it in detail because it probably answers your questions fully.

Comment: i think that if you are famous or important you can almost publish in every journal. I have seen papers about the Riemann zeros published in physics journals :D only because they said WKB approximation but the model did not much to do with physics i.e Berry and Keating model